# MySQL Unique Constraint, on Update, set exiting to NULL

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I am sure there is a way to search for this to find an existing answer, but most of the results deal with either enforcing a unique column by blocking the update or doing a swap of unique values between two rows (which apparently is broken in MySQL).  I don't want to swap I just want the row that currently has the unique value to be updated to `NULL`.

Here is how I could do it with two queries (with a two column table where the second column, person_id must be unique):

```
UPDATE bathroom_occupant
SET person_id = NULL
WHERE person_id = '$person_id';

UPDATE bathroom_occupant
SET person_id = '$person_id' 
WHERE bathroom_id = '$new_bathroom_id';
```

The above removes the `person_id` from it's current `bathroom_id` pairing and then places the `person_id` with it's new `bathroom_id` pairing. What I would like is to have only one query, which either uses some form of `COALESCE` to set the one row to NULL and the other to the `person_id` or use some table-level rule, similar I would think to a unique constraint, where running the second query alone automatically sets the column value to NULL for any other row already set to the unique value.

To use a simpler example: I know that a unique constraint can be used to prevent a student from enrolling in two sections of the same class. But rather than prevent by blocking, is it possible to prevent by "moving"?

Comment: You could implement that kind of logic in a "before insert" trigger but I'm not sure if doing that much work in trigger is a good idea.

Comment: Why does this need to happen in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

This is trickier than I imagined; first I investigated using triggers as suggested by acfrancis in the comments, but in a MySQL trigger you cannot update the table which the trigger is on - so both an INSERT trigger and an UPDATE trigger are out. This would be a possibility if your DBMS supported it.

So, you're left with the constraints concept, and you need to think about what it is you are restricting. If you want to make sure that one person is not recorded as being in more than one bathroom then you can add the relevant constraint, as below:

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bathroom_occupant;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE bathroom_occupant (bathroom_id INT, person_id INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE bathroom_occupant ADD CONSTRAINT
    -> UNIQUE INDEX person_id (person_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Then person 1 goes into bathroom 1, person 2 goes into bathroom 2

```
mysql> INSERT INTO bathroom_occupant (bathroom_id, person_id) VALUES (1, 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO bathroom_occupant (bathroom_id, person_id) VALUES (2, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Then when you want to update the bathroom that a person is in, you use an INSERT query and add an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. Below person 1 moves to bathroom 2

```
mysql> INSERT INTO bathroom_occupant (bathroom_id, person_id) VALUES (2, 1)
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bathroom_id = VALUES(bathroom_id);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM bathroom_occupant;
+-------------+-----------+
| bathroom_id | person_id |
+-------------+-----------+
|           2 |         1 |
|           2 |         2 |
+-------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, there are two records for bathroom 2 - because our constraint was only that one person is not in more than one bathroom. In the real world, this is ok - two people can go into the same bathroom. And I think it works for your other example - students enrolling into two sections of the same class (many students can be in the same section, but one student can only be in one).

However, you called your table bathroom_occupant - this name, to me, suggests that this table shows who is the occupant for each bathroom - and perhaps that you want each bathroom to only have one occupant. If this is what you need - i.e. you have a constraint on each person can only be in one bathroom and each bathroom can only contain one person - then this becomes even more difficult. I think that the logic to kick person 2 out of bathroom 2 when person 1 enters is beyond what MySQL can do internally. If you were to add another constraint on the table, this time for bathroom_id then the inserts will fail because the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement only fixes the problem for one record.

If you're happy that multiple people can be in one bathroom, then you can use the following code whenever you want to put someone into a bathroom:

```
INSERT INTO bathroom_occupant (bathroom_id, person_id) 
VALUES ('$new_bathroom_id', '$person_id')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bathroom_id = VALUES(bathroom_id);
```

It's one query - as requested. :-)

Comment: Wow. Very nice work. I have not tested to confirm it fits the specs of what I have in mind, but I can tell it will get me closer to what I need (or closer to deciding on a permanent solution) so +1 until I can mess with it a bit. The underlying idea is a 1-to-1 relationship where, in the example case, bathrooms would be fixed "slots" while occupants could vary over time. We don't want `person A` to occupy more than one slot, but the schema's logic is built more on the idea that there is only one `bathroom 1` to occupy and thus can't accidentally have multiple occupants.